# Propriety of a Tag for "Counter-Missionary" Related Questions

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags, question-catalog

We have a number of questions about interpreting passages in the *T'nakh* (or the like) with explicit contrast to how Christian understand such verses (or ideas) as supporting Christian belief.  Does the community feel it is appropriate to have a tag to identify such questions?  What would be the preferred tag (counter-missionary, polemic, "know-what-to-answer", other)? Should it be limited to questions constructed explicitly or should it be used for questions touching upon such controversies implicitly?

Possible questions for which this tag would be relevant:

[Why don't Jews think Jesus is the messiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8857/899)

[Isaiah 53:8 "He was stricken" or "They were stricken"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33568/899)

[If a virgin birth actually disqualifies a Messianic candidate, how then should Isaiah 7:14 be interpreted?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43708/899)

[What parts of the Septuagint are and are not reliable?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34203/899)

[Translation to Greek](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18819/899)

[Does the idea of Moshiach ben Yosef negate the anti missionary argument against the second coming?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49030/899)

[Is there a source that the Messiah can die and return?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16733/899)

[Is Psalm 110 considered messianic?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28784/899)

[Is Mashiach an incarnation of God according to any Jewish tradition?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/32187/899)

[What does Isaiah 9:6 mean?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34228/899)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for a tag that collects questions not by the content of the question but by what its answers could be useful for. That's not generally what we use tags for. If it was, we could theoretically end up with endless tags for Q&As that could provide good devar Torah fodder, Q&As that could be useful to teachers, Q&As that are beginner-level, etc.

Instead, I think it would be worthwhile to create and maintain [catalogs](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/question-catalog) of such collections (whichever people are interested in creating and maintaining) here in Meta. You're off to a great start.

For people interested in *following* new questions that invite counter-missionary expertise, perhaps someone could create, e.g. a Twitter account that tweets out links to them when they come up. It takes very little time to set up a Twitter account, and it would take very little time per post for someone dedicated to the cause to paste question titles and links into it. At our average rate of ~12 questions per day, it shouldn't be hard to review each day's questions to find the ones that qualify.

Comment: I'm not sure how this doesn't constitute part of the question's content, especially when the contrast is stated explicitly?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Why can't we have tags that would help us find answers based on what they could be used for?  Is that written in stone by Stack Exchange?

Comment: @BruceJames This answer includes an argument against such a use of tags.

Answer (score -2):

I think most of these should be labeled with the "Christianity" tag.

"Counter-missionary" suggests an agenda, which we would prefer to avoid. Most people need Google to know what polemic means.

So I think the "Christianity" tag would be appropriate. Obviously, this tag is used for questions about Christianity as relates to Judaism, or they would be off-topic for the site.  Perhaps you can create one called "Christian arguments" if you wish to be more specific.

Comment: If we had a "counter-missionary" tag, I'd be more  active as it is a specialty of mine having converted from Christianity. But tagging these questions as "Christianity" doesn't fit with all of the examples that the OP mentioned because, for one reason, there are other applications.  For example, the question of whether the messiah can be someone who was resurrected is an issue with those who believe that the Lubavitcher Rebbe is the Messiah.  In addition, that question is also fundamental to any discussion of Rambam's description in Hilchos Melachim regarding how we will recognize the Messiah.